# How to call/edit all html elements with class names that are found inside an array?

Tags: javascript, css, arrays

I have managed to create the array with the names that I need. These names are pushed or removed from the array based on user’s clicks on various html elements(buttons).

I am attempting to use the values collected within the array to call changes upon html elements that have class names corresponding/matching the names within the array.

I have managed to create a function that activates a window alert that allows me to see and verify that I am able to cycle through all elements collected within the array. But I got stuck. I couldn’t figure out how to use the individual values/names within the array to call the specific classes of html elements.

I have tried:

```
for (var a = 0; a < array.length; a++) {
   document.getElelemntsByClassName(“.”+array[a]).classList.add(“new”);
//and//

   document.querySelectorAll(“.”+array[a]).classList.add(“new”); 
//none of them worked. So I wasn’t able to get through to the specific html elements.//

   window.alert(“.”+array[a]); 
//This responds properly. I can get multiple alerts, one at the time, with all the names I am expecting to see.//
}
```

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: `document.getElementsByClassName` not `document.getElelemntsByClassName`

Comment: classList is a property of Node, both your selectors returns a NodeList.

Comment: Yes... of course. Misspelled it.

Comment: Both getElementsByClassName and querySelectorAll return collections (HTMLCollection, and NodeList). There is no classList property on them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you want to use an object instead of an array, since indexes on an array will change as you remove items. That said, you may not even need the object, depending on what you want to do with the element. In the snippet below, I added `classNames` as an object to treat it as an associative array, for example:

```js
// This is shared between two functions
const LIST_ITEM_SELECTOR = '.js-list-item'

// Get top-level elements
const listElement = document.querySelector('.js-list')
const listItemTemplate = document.querySelector('.js-list-item-template')
const addButton = document.querySelector('.js-add-button')
const logButton = document.querySelector('.js-log-button')

// Replaces "array" from your example
const classNames = {}

// Removes the list item from the list element (also delete from classNames)
const handleDelete = e => {
  const parentListItem = e.currentTarget.closest(LIST_ITEM_SELECTOR)
  const listItemId = parentListItem.dataset.id
  delete classNames[listItemId]
  parentListItem.remove()
}

// Updates after each "Add"
let nextId = 0

const handleAdd = () => {

  // Build new element from the template
  const newListItem = listItemTemplate.content
    .cloneNode(true)
    .querySelector(LIST_ITEM_SELECTOR)
  
  // Add class to the element and the "classNames" object
  const className = `id-${nextId}`
  newListItem.classList.add(className)
  classNames[nextId] = className
  
  // Add data-id
  newListItem.dataset.id = nextId
  
  // Update text
  newListItem.querySelector('.js-text').textContent = `Item Text ${nextId}`
  
  // Add delete event listener to the nested x button
  newListItem.querySelector('.js-x-button').addEventListener('click', handleDelete)
  
  // Append the newListItem to the end of the list
  listElement.appendChild(newListItem)
  
  // Prep the nextId for the next "Add" click
  nextId += 1
}

addButton.addEventListener('click', handleAdd)

logButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
  console.dir(classNames)
})
```

```html
<button class="js-add-button">Add</button>

<ul class="js-list"></ul>

<template class="js-list-item-template">
  <li class="js-list-item">
    <span class="js-text">Item Text</span>
    <button class="js-x-button">x</button>
  </li>
</template>

<button class="js-log-button">Log Out Data</button>
```

Comment: Thanks BDawg. It would be easy indeed if the array had just a few elements. But unfortunately, the array doesn’t even exist until the user starts clicking on things. The array is dynamically created. Somehow I need to convert the values inside my array so I can use them to reach the classes of the respective html elements.

Comment: Sorry, I must have been only paying partial attention and following the code. I'll rework this answer

Comment: Thanks BDawg... your answer is covering more than I asked for. Although I have chosen a different route, you answer definitely helped me to see things from another perspective too. Thanks again for your swift reply.

Comment: Happy it helped!